# Finding the elementary Divisors of a Matrix (Jordan Canonical Form - Shilov)

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, jordan-normal-form

In Shilov's *Linear Algebra*, he defines an *elementary divisor of the operator $A$* as follows,

$$E_p(\lambda)=\frac{D_{p+1}(\lambda)}{D_{p}(\lambda)}$$

where $D_{p}(\lambda)$ is the greatest common divisor of polynomials generated by minors of order $p$ of the matrix $A - \lambda I$.

How would we use this to actually calculate the elementary divisors from this? Do we actually have to calculate all the minors of order $p$ and then find the GCD?

Most other texts talk about generalized eigenvectors and generalized eigenspaces. How is that related to the above?